# accessing a itemdatabound handler for a nasted listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have a nested list view within a list view and i am trying to access its item data bound function but having no luck with it could anyone help me with this matter? ive also tried to use the outer listview's itemdatabound to do the things im trying to do but had no look.
Thanks in advance :)

```
    Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound
    'determins if you created the comment
    If ListView1.EditIndex >= 0 Then

        Dim dataItem As ListViewDataItem = CType(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
        If dataItem.DisplayIndex = ListView1.EditIndex Then

            Dim postid As String = DirectCast(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem.DataItem, "Post"), String)
            Dim commentTxt As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("EditPostTxt"), TextBox)
            commentTxt.Text = postid
        End If
    End If

    Try
        Dim GetdataItem As ListViewDataItem = CType(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
        Dim getPostId As Guid = DirectCast(DataBinder.Eval(GetdataItem.DataItem, "PostId"), Guid)

        Dim listview As ListView = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("CommentsOnPosts"), ListView)
        Dim loadcomments = From p In db.CommentPosts Where p.PostId = getPostId Select p.CommentPostId, p.PostId, p.aspnet_User.Tmp_Profile.DisaplyPictureSmall, fullname = p.aspnet_User.FirstName & " " & p.aspnet_User.LastName, profileid = p.aspnet_User.Tmp_Profile.ProfileId.ToString, p.Post, p.Date Order By [Date] Descending

        listview.DataSource = loadcomments
        listview.DataBind()
        Try
            cc.aloudToSeeDeleteSubPost(e, User.Identity.Name, "CommentDeleteTxt", "CommentEditTxt")
        Catch ex As Exception
            a.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        a.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    cc.aloudToSeeDelete(e, User.Identity.Name, "linkbutton1", "linkbutton2")

End Sub

    Public Sub aloudToSeeDeleteSubPost(ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs, ByVal username As String, ByVal DelButton As String, ByVal editBut As String)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        Dim dataItem As ListViewDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)

        If dataItem.DataItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim postid As Guid = DirectCast(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem.DataItem, "PostId"), Guid)

            Dim getMessageFrom = (From p In db.CommentPosts Where p.PostId = postid).Single
            If Not getMessageFrom.FromId = uif.returnUserID(username) Then
                Dim DeleteButton As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl(DelButton), LinkButton)
                Dim EditButton As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl(editBut), LinkButton)
                DeleteButton.Visible = False
                EditButton.Visible = False
            End If
            If getMessageFrom.ToId = uif.returnUserID(username) Then
                Dim DeleteButton As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl(DelButton), LinkButton)
                DeleteButton.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the `ItemCreated` event

```
Dim listview As ListView = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("CommentsOnPosts"), ListView)
AddHandler listview.ItemDataBound, AddressOf ListViewCommentsOnPosts_ItemDataBound
```